# How to show that this function is an isomorphisn??

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Thank you all for helping me in the last question :)

[image]

the question is how to prove that the 'natural map' from k to K is an isomorphism?
I checked that it is injective, but can't show it is surjective...Could anyone help me show it is surjective?

Answer (score 2):

$\pi$ is injective , hence $k$ is isomorphic to it's image $k'=\pi(k)$ which is a subfield of $K$, since $K$ is an algebraic over $k$, it is also algebraic over $k'$. Then $K=k'=\pi(k)$ since $k'$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: how do we know that K itself is algebraically closed?

Comment: $K$ is algebraic over $k'$ and $k'$ algebraically closed then $K=k'$: that is; if $x\in K$ then $x$ is algebraic over $k'$ hence $x\in k'$.

Comment: oh, I understand. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The (algebraic) extension $K/k$ is finite. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, $K$ must be $k$ itself.